# Excel Macro to format date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with some string value in excel file.

```
   Col A
20131022082702
20131022082702
20131022082739
20131022082739
```

I want to convert each cell value in to date format e.g. `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM`

```
20131022082702   // should be formatted as 2013/10/22 08:27
```

I was just wondering if is there any built in function we can use to format it using some kind of macro?

One approach I can think of is taking sub string and writing custom logic in macro. Any other work around for it will be much appreciated !

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the `TEXT` worksheet function, you can format it to look like a date/time stamp, and Excel will convert it to a "real" value.  You can then format it as you wish:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"0000\/00\/00 00\:00\:00")
```

**EDIT**:  In VBA, one can use this line to do the conversion.  Similar algorithm, but using native VBA functions:

```
cdate(format(N,"0000 00 00 00:00:00"))
```

where `N` is your 14 digit number

Comment: Just a quick question @Ron, can I use the same function in my macro? Actually I want to have this functionality through macro.

Comment: @Rockstar You can, but I'll add a method that uses native VBA functions

Comment: Thanks @Ron, very much appreciated your help !

Answer (score 1):

More long-winded than @Ron's answer but another method is separating the string out:

```
=TEXT(DATE(MID(A1,1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))+TIME(MID(A1,9,2),MID(A1,11,2),MID(A1,13,2)),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
```